# Tuning LDA Topic Models

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling

Suppose I build a LDA topic model using gensim or sklearn and assign top topics to each document. But some of documents don't match top topics assigned. Besides trying out different numbers of topics or use coherence score to get the optimal number of topics, what other tricks can I use to improve my model?

Answer (score 0):

LDA also (semi-secretly) takes the parameters `alpha` and `beta`.  Think of `alpha` as the parameter that tells LDA how many topics each document should be generated from.  `beta` is the parameter that tells LDA how many topics each `word` should be in.  You can play with these and you may get better results.

However, LDA is an unsupervised model, and even the perfect settings for `k`, `alpha`, and `beta` will result in some incorrectly assigned documents.  If your data isn't preprocessed well, it almost doesn't matter what you assign the parameters, it will always produce poor results.

Answer (score 0):

A sample python implementation for @rchurch4's answer:

We can try out a different number of topics, and different values of **alpha** and **beta(eta)** to increase the **coherence score**. **High coherence score** is good for our model

```
def calculate_coherence_score(n, alpha, beta):
    lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=n, 
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha=alpha,
                                           per_word_topics=True,
                                           eta = beta)
    coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=tokeize_article, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
    coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
    return coherence_lda

#list containing various hyperparameters
no_of_topics = [2,5,7,10,12,14]
alpha_list = ['symmetric',0.3,0.5,0.7]
beta_list = ['auto',0.3,0.5,0.7]


for n in no_of_topics:
    for alpha in alpha_list:
        for beta in beta_list:
            coherence_score = calculate_coherence_score(n, alpha, beta)
            print(f"n : {n} ; alpha : {alpha} ; beta : {beta} ; Score : {coherence_score}")
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if the so-called `beta` and `eta`  are equivalent? I've seen it used differently in a lot of topic modelling papers.  A higher `eta` makes the topic preferences "smoother" over words ?